# conditional join - how intelligently will mysql handle implicit information

Tags: sql, mysql, join, relational-database

just came across a join which is only necessary given a certain condition is met.

So I thought about how to forego the join if it is not necessary.

Some googling and investigation on SO confronted me with rather complex queries, involving unions etc.

Let me show you a simple example for two tables t1 and t2 with two fields id and val.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val, t2.val
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Now t1.val can have a special value -1, which makes joining superfluous, because then t2.val is always `NULL`.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val, IF(t1.val = -1, NULL, t2.val)
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

So, if I join and every reference to a field from the joined table is conditional and the condition isn't met, so the join is definitely superfluous ... does MySQL recognize that and foregoes the join?

Because my mathematical intuition tells me that this is a Std-situation that should be handled efficiently by a professional database like MySQL.

Has somebody insider information about that?

Best regards

Raffael

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out on your SQL statements. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: Why should I? Bart is my personal editor ... :-)

Comment: Because if you [build a man a fire](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/build_a_man_a_fire-and_he-ll_be_warm_for_a_day/225760.html), he will be warm for the night. If you set a man on fire, he will be warm the rest of his life.

Comment: how wise ... also I am nice, I give new guys the chance to edit my posts so they can get the editor-badge! ;-)

Comment: It seems like your mathematical intuition could do with a good dose of Codd.

Comment: Seems like you'r asking about something alike 'table elimiation' (see: http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=58 ), but not quite still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join condition (`t1.id = t2.id`, in the example) is the sole criteria for determining what the result rows are. Because the value of `t1.val` isn't referenced in the join condition, it won't affect what is or isn't included. If you want to elide rows whene `t1.val` is -1, include a test in the join condition:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val, t2.val
  FROM t1 
    JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.val != -1
```

If you still want the rows from t1 where `t1.val=-1` to appear in the result, use a `[LEFT JOIN`][1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join), which will also include all rows from t1 where there is no row in t2 with the same ID:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val, t2.val
  FROM t1 
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.val != -1
```

Comment: so you know for sure that MySQL doesn't care about what is referenced at all? or are you just guessing? b/c there is lots of algorithmic optimization going on in MySQL usually ... that's why one (usually) should have the DB have handled as much as possible.

Comment: The join takes place before the [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29), so the expression involving `t2.val` can't affect the join. Even if you don't select any columns from table `t2`, MySQL will still join the two tables.

Comment: your query makes sense and would solve the problem. but my example is simplified and just serving the purpose to clarify. I am adressing the internal ongoings, not this specific example.

Comment: well that would be an answer to my question! How do you know that? I mean just b/c that's a standard way of processing data doesn't mean some simple optimizations couldn't have been integrated.

Comment: If sample code in an answer is merely illustrative of implementation, then sample code in an answer is likewise illustrate of technique. Placing additional tests in join conditions and `LEFT JOINS` should work in your actual statement.

Comment: Well ... you have your point ... the answer is yours! I guess I have to rethink the question to get my point across. I was more interested in how intelligent MySQL handles queries.

Comment: @Raffael1984. MyNonSQK is not "intelligent".  It is not even standard. If it were even close to the commercial Dbs, you could Show Query Plan, which would identify exactly what it was doing, and you would not have to guess or ask questions.